# A question on the derivation of the PDF of the general normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, normal-distribution, chain-rule

If $$\Phi(z)=\int_{-\infty}^z\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-t^2/2}dt$$ $$\phi(z)=\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-z^2/2}$$ I need to prove that $\frac d{dx} \Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=\frac 1\sigma \phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$.

when I substitute and differentiate I get $\frac d{dx} \Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$. According to my text, there is a chain rule that has to be applied here but I don't know why and how. May you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, by applying the standard [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),
$$
\left[f\left(\frac {x-\mu}\sigma\right)\right]'=\color{red}{\frac 1\sigma}\times f'\left(\frac {x-\mu}\sigma\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks so much :). So, $1/\sigma$ is the derivative of ($(x-\mu)/\sigma$), right?

Comment: @Abdu Magdy Right, differentiating with respect to $x$ gives, $$\left(\frac {x-\mu}\sigma\right)'=\color{red}{\frac 1\sigma}.$$You are welcome!